# int value with positive only entry

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to create a table and I can only have positive values for an INT, how would I do that?

```
CREATE TABLE Ingredients(
IngredientID    INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
IngredientName  VARCHAR(255),
IngredientClassID   SMALLINT    NOT NULL,
MeasureAmountID      SMALLINT    NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: positive entry on which _column_ ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this...

```
CREATE TABLE Ingredients(
IngredientID    INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY,
IngredientName  VARCHAR(255),
IngredientClassID   SMALLINT    NOT NULL,
MeasureAmountID      SMALLINT    NOT NULL,
CHECK (IngredientClassID>0),
CHECK (MeasureAmountID>0)

);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [Check constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm) for each column to accept only positive values.

```
CREATE TABLE Ingredients(
IngredientID    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY constraint IngredientID_Positive
check (IngredientID >= 0),
IngredientName  VARCHAR(255),
IngredientClassID   SMALLINT    NOT NULL,
MeasureAmountID      SMALLINT    NOT NULL
);
```